# Installing Tensorflow with Anaconda3 - Python 3 - Windows raises exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to install Tensorflow but I am getting an exception.

My PC runs Windows and has Python 3 installed through Anaconda 3.

The output is the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to see my optometrist.  I can't read these.

Comment: Are you able to install/uninstall other packages? The error is a Permission denied, which usually means you don't have acces rights to the folder? Have you checked this?

Comment: Given that this question features text artefacts rendered as images, I think it is missing a [mcve]. I will try to put it on hold for now.

Answer (score 0):

try `python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Only if you have CUDA 8 or 9 graphics card.  If you're an older GeForce you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I run the code as an administrator and the problem was resolved